# gcc soname unrecognized command line

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile

I'm compiling `sipXtapi` and I need to compile with this line

```
gcc -shared  -DPIC  .libs/codec_pcmapcmu_la-CodecPcmaWrapper.o .libs/codec_pcmapcmu_la-CodecPcmuWrapper.o .libs/codec_pcmapcmu_la-G711.o .libs/codec_pcmapcmu_la-PlgPcmaPcmu.o   -lc -W1,-soname=codec_pcmapcmu.so -o .libs/codec_pcmapcmu.so
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-W1,-soname=codec_pcmapcmu.so’
```

and this is the **Makefile.am**:

```
## Process this file with automake to produce Makefile.in

INCLUDES = -I$(top_srcdir)/include -I$(top_srcdir)/../sipXportLib/include -I$(top_srcdir)/contrib/libspandsp/src

pkgdata_LTLIBRARIES = codec_pcmapcmu.la

codec_pcmapcmu_la_SOURCES = \
CodecPcmaWrapper.c \
CodecPcmuWrapper.c \
G711.c \
PlgPcmaPcmu.c

if PCMAPCMU_STATIC
    codec_pcmapcmu_la_CFLAGS  = -DCODEC_STATIC
    codec_pcmapcmu_la_LDFLAGS = -module -avoid-version -static else
    codec_pcmapcmu_la_LDFLAGS = -module -avoid-version

all-local: codec_pcmapcmu.la
    echo "Installing plugin codec_pcmapcmu.so ..."
    cp -f .libs/codec_pcmapcmu.so @DEFAULT_CODECS_PATH@

clean-local:
    rm -f @DEFAULT_CODECS_PATH@/codec_pcmapcmu.so endif
```

how can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a spelling error there `-W1` should be `-Wl` (that's a lower case `L` instead of the digit `1`)

Comment: You would search through the build files (Makefile.am, configure.ac and anyting else that this build system uses, and replace -W1 with -Wl)

Comment: the problem is to find because I have a lot of files with -w

Comment: Use `grep -r -- -W1 .` , or use an editor that can easily search through all files in a directory ?

Comment: I don't find that one but It's the answer that I need :D

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33636294/gcc-error-adding-symbols-sipxtapi tyr to see this please